# Any way to postpone PHP processing to after HTML loads?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a page that loads a bunch of PHP chunks which take a lot of time.
They are initially hidden, until the user pops them open with a jQuery slideToggle.

Is there any way to make the HTML load first, and load the PHP after?

Here are the relevant snippets:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $('a.toggler').click(function(){
           $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
        return false; //ensures no anchor jump
    });
});
</script>
...
<div class='gallerysection'>
    <a href='#' class='toggler'>Logos &amp; Type</a>
    <div class='toggle'><?php $album='1755641';include('VimeoAlbumSimple.php'); ?></div>
    <a href='#' class='toggler'>Infographics &amp; UIs</a>
    <div class='toggle'><?php $album='1755635';include('VimeoAlbumSimple.php'); ?></div>                
</div>
```

The `include('VimeoAlbumSimple.php')` loads a bunch of images and links from vimeo, and each call takes several seconds to load. There are more than 10 on the page.

This is `VimeoAlbumSimple.php`:

```
require_once('/home/dzg/zinclabs.com/assets/vimeolib.php');
$vimeo = new phpVimeo('807d405c3bf97d7c20060dabce349b6a', '9cc9d85a3b91b1a7');
$vimeo->setToken('274e2c915371a405ac1ec1cd7c3a72a5','3fe84c74bd6b4a9f736a41cb5709a76ec222686c');

$result = $vimeo->call('vimeo.albums.getVideos', array('album_id' => $album,full_response => '1'));
$videos = $result->videos->video;

echo '<div class="gallery">';
foreach ($videos as $video) {echo '
    <div class="item">
        <a href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$video->id
        .'?autoplay=1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;wmode=transparent" title="'
        .$video->title.'" class="zoombox zgallery1">'    
        .'<img src="posters/'.$video->id.'.jpg" />'
        .'<span class="text">
            <span class="title">'.$video->title.'</span>'
            .'<span class="duration">'.ltrim(gmdate("i:s", $video->duration),"0").'</span>'
            .'<span class="description">'.nl2br($video->description).'</span>'
            .'<div class="clear"></div>
        </span>
        </a>
    </div>';
}

echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Sure, delaying the serverside language until after the clientside has loaded sounds totally possible? You should probably look into loading the markup with Ajax as needed, if it loads too slow.

Comment: @adeneo Sorry I have no idea what that means.

Comment: PHP executes on the serverside long before the HTML is even sent to the user, so delaying it is'nt possible. You could however not load certain parts of your page that are'nt visible on pageload, and load those parts as needed with ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot delay PHP processing after HTML has rendered because PHP is what produces the HTML in the first place.

What you can do is use AJAX to load pieces of the web page after the "main" layout has loaded. For example:

```
<div class='gallerysection'>
    <a href='#' class='toggler'>Logos &amp; Type</a>
    <div class='toggle' data-url="VimeoAlbumSimple.php?album=1755641"></div>
    <a href='#' class='toggler'>Infographics &amp; UIs</a>
    <div class='toggle' data-url="VimeoAlbumSimple.php?album=1755635"></div>
</div>

jQuery(function($){
    $('.gallerysection .toggle').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.load($this.data("url"));
    });
});
```

Here I have used an [HTML5 data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to associate each div in the slideshow with the URL that will render its contents. When the DOM is ready jQuery fetches this url with [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and makes an AJAX request with [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to fetch the HTML and insert it inside the (initially empty) placeholder.

Comment: I see ... I tried that, and it worked to load those chunks after the HTML. But then the PHP gives me errors: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'VimeoAPIException' with message 'Invalid signature' in /home/.../vimeolib.php:239 Stack trace: #0 /home/.../vimeolib.php(275): phpVimeo->_request('vimeo.albums.ge...', Array, 'GET', 'http://vimeo.co...', true) #1 /home/dzg/zinclabs.com/VimeoAlbumSimple.php(6): phpVimeo->call('vimeo.albums.ge...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /home/dzg/zinclabs.com/assets/vimeolib.php on line 239`

Comment: I've added the contents of VimeoAlbumSimple.php above

Comment: @Ze'ev: Well, debugging that is clearly outside the scope of the question and (more importantly) outside the scope of SO as well -- a very localized issue. Grab a reference for the Vimeo API you are using and have at it. :-)

Comment: I added an `echo $album` to the PHP ... and it seems that is not getting passed by this method. Maybe I need a `$album = $_GET['album'];`

Comment: @Ze'ev: Yes, you definitely need that.

Comment: I've run into another issue. The chunks generated by the PHP have `a`'s with `class='zoombox'` which used to make them open up in a lightbox-like thing. Now that no longer works! I'm guessing it's because the jquery for the zoombox didn't 'see' those anchors. Any way to make THAT 'load' after the PHP chunks??